# Issue setting event to clear columns in my sql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create an event (ClearTimes) in a mysql database (edata), to run every 24 hrs at 11pm, that clears 2 columns (Shift, Lunchtime). This is what I typed to create the event:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE 
EVENT `ClearTimes` 
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY STARTS '2015-12-05 23:00:00' 
DO BEGIN

    -- clear "Shift" column
    UPDATE edata SET shift = '';

    -- clear "Lunchtimes" column
    UPDATE edata SET Lunchtime = '';


END $$


DELIMITER ;
```

The issue is that the event ran on the 5th at 11pm, and then never ran again. I of course want the event to run every 24 hours @ 11pm. Any Ideas?

Comment: not sure how that could run at 11pm, since you're specifying 10:30pm...

Comment: sorry i edited to original post

Comment: Is the event scheduler enabled?

Comment: Yes, the event scheduler is on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after all this time I figured out the issue, some one was running a restart on the computer for updates so the pc was never on when it was trying to clear... changed the time and it has been working great.

Sorry for the confusion.